# MonoGame / XNA Draw Polygon in Spritebatch

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

i am currently writing a game with MonoGame and I need to draw textured shapes. I want to draw polygons with 4 corners.
All my renderstuff is done with the spritebatch.
I tried to use TriangleStripes, but it does not work very well for me, because I don't have any experience with shaders and mixing this with the rest of the spritebatch-rendercode seems complicated.
One solution i thought about was to draw a quad and strech the texture with texturecoordinats. Is this possible somehow? I can't find something about this in relation to the spritebatch.
Does anyone have tutorials or knows how to archive my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using spritebatch will stretch the texture if you set a destination rect that's larger than source rect. You can also set a source rect that doesn't cover the entire texture if you only want to render part of it. Do you need to have the textrued skewed as well or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, the texture should be skewed as well, that's my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to draw your texture in a non-rectangular way you can't use `SpriteBatch`. But drawing polygons isn't hard either and you can use `BasicEffect` so you don't have to worry about shaders.
Start by setting up your Vertex and Index arrays:

```
BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(device);
basicEffect.Texture = myTexture;
basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;

VertexPositionTexture[] vert = new VertexPositionTexture[4];
vert[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
vert[1].Position = new Vector3(100, 0, 0);
vert[2].Position = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);
vert[3].Position = new Vector3(100, 100, 0);

vert[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
vert[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
vert[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
vert[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);

short[] ind = new short[6];
ind[0] = 0;
ind[1] = 2;
ind[2] = 1;
ind[3] = 1;
ind[4] = 2;
ind[5] = 3;
```

`BasicEffect` is great a standard shader, you can use it to draw textures, colors and even apply lighting to it.

`VertexPositionTexture` is how your vertex buffer is set up.

You can use `VertexPositionColor` if you only want colors and `VertexPositionColorTexture` if you want both (tinting the texture with a color).

The `ind` array says in what order you draw the two triangles making up the quad.

Then in your render loop you do this:

```
foreach (EffectPass effectPass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) 
{
    effectPass.Apply();
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vert, 0, vert.Length, ind, 0, ind.Length / 3);
}
```

That's it! 
This is a very brief introduction, I suggest you play around with this and if you get stuck there's a ton of tutorials and information on this, google is your friend.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i didn't know about the basic effect. All tutorials i have seen used a custom shader and monogame was not able to compile them