# c# / Monogame : Draw a Polygon primitive?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to draw a polygon of a solid color. I'm given a vector of 2D vectors, ordered such that there will be an edge from v0 to v1 to v2 to ... to vn to v0.

Does such a primitive exist?

Comment: Don't want to mark this as a duplicate, but does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136388/monogame-xna-draw-polygon-in-spritebatch

Comment: i did that, played around but couldn't figure how to change the shape, by modifying coordinates of each vertices I either got a rectangle or a full screen thingy.

Answer (score 3):

Credit to Stefan Agartsson for the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136388/monogame-xna-draw-polygon-in-spritebatch) this answer's code is based upon.

To describe the vertices as edges instead of triangles, You can use the `PrimitiveType.LineStrip` instead of `PrimitiveType.TriangleList` you have to adjust the index and counts as well since each vertex is used only once.

```
BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(device);
basicEffect.Texture = myTexture;
basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;

VertexPositionTexture[] vert = new VertexPositionTexture[4];
vert[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); //These connect in order
vert[1].Position = new Vector3(100, 0, 0);
vert[2].Position = new Vector3(100, 100, 0);
vert[3].Position = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);

vert[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
vert[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
vert[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
vert[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);

short[] ind = new short[n+1]; // the +1 is to close the shape
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   ind[i] = i;
ind[n] = 0; // return to start to close.
```

Then in your render loop you do this:

```
foreach (EffectPass effectPass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) 
{
    effectPass.Apply();
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(
        PrimitiveType.LineStrip, vert, 0, vert.Length, ind, 0, ind.Length);
}
```